# How to pass a numpy array though a function when the function contains conditional if statements?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, astropy

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.cosmology import FlatLambdaCDM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cosmopar = FlatLambdaCDM(H0 = 67.8,Om0 = 0.3)

td_min = 0.1
d = -1

def t_L(z_arb):
    return cosmopar.lookback_time(z_arb).value

def t_d(z_f,z_m):
    return t_L(z_f)-t_L(z_m)

def P_t(z_f,z_m):
    if (td_min<t_d):
        return t_d**d
    else:
        return 0
```

Now if I define a numpy array `zf_trial1 = np.linspace(0,30,100)` and try to pass it through the function using the command `P_t(zf_trial1,3)`, the function returns the following error statement:

"The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Now I understand why this error is popping up - when making the comparizon with `td_min` in the if statement, passing an 'array' with several elements leads to certain elements of the array satisfying the condition of the if statement and certain elements failing the condition; however, I am not sure how to fix this. Overall, all I want to do is pass each element of the NumPy array `zf_trial1` through `P_t(z_f,z_m)`.

I tried the `np.vectorize()` function but this doesn't seem to be working all that well and the results seem to be haywire since when I plot the results of the function, the graph I am receiving is different from the one I am receiving if I manually input values into the P_t function and then plot it. What I tried is as follows:

```
Pt_vector = np.vectorize(P_t)
Pt_res = Pt_vector(zf_trial1,3)

plt.scatter(zf_trial1,Pt_res)
```

Comment: just iterate - as you would with  a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused since `P_t` takes `z_f` and `z_m` as argument but they aren't used in the function at all, thus I don't really get how it should be used, thus I'll try answer the question in a general way.

You can use `np.where` to make a filter, in your function, like so

```py
def ex(arr,max_value):
      """
      arr: np.array
      max_value: int


      All values in `arr` below `max_value`
      are raised to a power of `d`.
      Values below are set as `0`
      """
      return np.where(arr < max_value, arr**d, 0)

d = 2
ex(np.arange(0,10),5) # array([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0])
```

or you can just use list-comprehension :

```py
a = np.array([P_t(v,z_m) for v in zf_trial1])
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! "I'm a bit confused since P_t takes z_f and z_m as argument but they aren't used in the function at all", I am a beginner to Python and programming in general, so please excuse me if I did not understand this question correctly; however, if you're asking why I am defining the variable z_m when I am just replacing it with an integer at the end, that is because in the actual code, z_m is indeed a variable and not a simple integer, and in the case of z_f, that is a variable I am integrating out using quad from scipy.integrate library.

Comment: Also, thank you for the suggestions, I tried using the 'list-comprehension' method, and it works perfectly!